# Youtube in iframe on a modal is not working in iOS Safari after the modal is hidden then re-opened

Tags: ios, iframe, youtube, embed, modal-dialog

I have a web app that is using Youtube videos embedded via iframes into a modal dialog window. In Safari on the iPad 3, iOS 5.1, the video plays properly the first time it's loaded. However, if the modal is hidden and then re-opened, the video will no longer be able to play. The player will display, but it's simply a black space with no controls. The YouTube watermark still appears, and can be clicked on.

The play button in the Safari control panel will play the audio of the video from where it left off, but the player still won't display any video. 
The "related video" suggestion images will appear once the audio reaches the end, and then the video can be replayed normally.

Does anyone know what's causing this behaviour? The embedding works as intended in all major desktop browsers, and is fine the first time in iOS. It's only when it's reopened in iOS Safari that it fails.

Comment: I'm getting this exact same behaviour - any YouTube video inside a jQuery dialog is broken after the first time a video is played.

Comment: @Chris Francis: As a workaround, I'm currently removing the iframe element when the modal window is closed, and re-rendering it when the modal is reopened. This isn't ideal, however, as any video progress is lost. It does work, though, so the app is usable.